# redux-saga 'call' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

saga.js

```
import { delay } from 'redux-saga'
import { put, takeLatest, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import axios from 'axios'; 

function fire(data) {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:3131/createUserBusinessInfo', data).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        return error;
    });
}

export function* createUserBusinessInfo(action) {
    console.log(UserBusinessInfoService)

    const userData = yield call(fire, action);
    yield put({
        type: 'CREATE_USER_BUSINESS_INFO',
        userData
    });
}

export function* createUserBusinessInfoSaga() {
    yield takeLatest('CREATE_USER_BUSINESS_INFO_SAGA', createUserBusinessInfo);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        helloSaga(),
        createUserBusinessInfoSaga()
    ])
}
```

**In info-component.js**

```
componentDidMount(){
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch({type: "CREATE_USER_BUSINESS_INFO_SAGA", data: {asdf : 444} });
    }
}
```

**Error**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misunderstood **`call`** in redux-saga is **`call`** in javascript and both are different

and

for redux-saga we have to import it like this

```
import { call ,put, takeEvery, all } from 'redux-saga/effects'
```